# Merge the [nextauth.js] tag into the [next-auth] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [next-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next-auth) tag has a filled out tag info and far more tagged questions. It seems like the [nextauth.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextauth.js) tag is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, these tags referred to the same thing and the majority of existing questions tagged [nextauth.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextauth.js) also had the [next-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next-auth) tag.

After I confirmed the 10 questions that only used [nextauth.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextauth.js) were all referring to NextAuth, I merged the tags together. I also allowed a synonym to be created [nextauth.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextauth.js) -> [next-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next-auth).

```
updating post history, 43 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 41 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 10 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'nextauth.js': [nextauth.js] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 1907
tag remapping of [next-auth] and [nextauth.js] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
4 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym nextauth.js -> next-auth was approved!
```